# How to get around 'Argument list too long' error when concatenating multiple gzip files?

Tags: gzip, cat

I am trying to concatenate around ~21,000 gzip files that are all located in a local directory so I can unzip 1 large gzip file then convert the unzipped file into a csv. Unfortunately this is over the maximum number of arguments that can be accepted by the cat command. I have tried using  `cat *gz > final.gz` as well as `ls *.gz | xargs cat` but both have given me the error 'Argument list too long'. How might I work around this error to concatenate all gzipped files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
find . -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 cat > final.gz
```

If there are `.gz` files in subdirectories of the current directory, and you only want the ones in the current directory, then add `-maxdepth 1` to the `find` options.

If you want to impose a particular order on the files, you can pipe through an appropriate `sort` between the `find` and the `xargs`.